# Is it possible to have team functionality using SVN rather than TFS, in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, team-foundation-server

I'm a huge fan of TFS and VS2010, but I work in a company where the source control solution is SVN, it is unlikely to change because all our customers are also using SVN. Having said that I'm also a huge fan of SVN.

I would however like to be able to handle stuff like TFS team functionality and project tracking in visual studio using SVN and not Team foundation server.

Is this possible with some plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.

Only thing supported with any SVN plug-in would be source control. Team functionality is not supported via SVN.